# Сервер на JS и клиент на Python

Tags: javascript, python, http

Пытаюсь настроить соединение JS и Python

**client.py**

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('localhost', 8841))
sock.listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()

print ('connected:', addr)

while True:
    sock.settimeout(60)
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    conn.send(data.upper())

conn.close()
```

**server.js**

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("Hello, your name is Pavel");
}).listen(8841);

console.log('Server running on port 8841');
```

Клиент ничего не принимает, в чем проблема?

Comment: В том, что сервер хочет http, а ты коннектишься по-другому?

Comment: А как правильно?

Comment: Отправить из питона http-запрос, очевидно

Comment: И вообще-то на питоне у вас тоже написан сервер, а не клиент

Comment: Не надо http надо сокеты

Comment: Любой http работает через сокеты... Тогда на js создайте обычный сокет-сервер,а не http